# Convert MMDDYYYY to date for PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime

I have a string with a date which is in this format MMDDYYYY (ie. 01132012, 01142012 etc.)

I need to do something on a page, if that string is 14 days or less from the current date.

ie. Today is 01132012, so any strings with 12312011 or a less date are going to be showing something on a page.

Can anyone help with this? I've tried

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime('01142012'));
```

But to no avail.

Comment: Become familiar with the PHP manual: [`strptime`](http://php.net/strptime).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the DateTime class of PHP

```
<?
  // current date
  $now = new DateTime();

  //your date
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdY', '01142012');

  // calculate difference 
  $diff = $now->diff($date);

  ...

  // output the date in format you want
  echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
?>
```

EDIT: I just realized, that your format isn't one supported by php. So you have to use alternate objectbuild.

Comment: Getting a blank page.

     $date = new DateTime('01142012');

 echo $date->format('m/d/Y');

Comment: @BloodyWorld It is better to use `DateTime::createFromFormat` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using strptime.

```
<?
$dt = strptime('01142012', '%m%d%Y');
echo sprintf("%02d/%02d/%04d", $dt['tm_mday'], $dt['tm_mon']+1, $dt['tm_year']+1900);
```

If you use PHP 5.3 or above, you can also use date_parse_from_format()

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 1):

How about some substr + mktime?

```
$string = '01142012';
$time = mktime(0, 0, 0, 
          substr($string, 0, 2),
          substr($string, 2, 2),
          substr($string, 4, 4)
        );
 echo date('d/m/Y', $time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try date('m-d-y', strtotime('01142012'));
```

could also try something like;

```
$var = strtotime('01142012');
$var2 = date ('F j, Y', $var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string input of '01142012' cannot be parsed by strtotime() as it is not a valid as it is returning -1 as an answer. To convert this into a valid date you will need to add either slashes or dashes to separate the numbers.

The easiest way would be to store the dates with the dashes or slashes, such as '01-14-2012' or '01/14/2012' in the database from now on or you are going to have to create your own function to convert the numbers into a valid form for strtotime().

To do this you could do something like this:

```
function makeValidDate($date) {

   $valid_date = array();
   $array = str_split($date); //split characters up

   foreach($array as $key => $character){
       if($key==2 || $key==4){
           $character = '-'.$character; //add relevant formatting to date
           $valid_date[] = $character; //add this to the formatted array
       }
       else{
           $valid_date[] = $character; // if not dashes or slashes needed add to valid array
       }
   }

   return implode($valid_date); // return the formmatted date for use with strtotime
}
```

You can then do this to get a valid date:

```
$valid_date = makeValidDate('01142012');    
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($valid_date));
```

I haven't tested this but you should get a good idea of what to do.

EDIT: Capi's idea is a lot cleaner!!

Answer (score 0):

try "preg_match(pattern,string on wich the pattern will be aplied)";
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
you can also define an offset. so first take te first 2 digits. than take the other 2 digits and after that get the other four digits. after that place them in one string. after that use maketime,strtotime,date. this kind of stupid solution but i only thought of that. hope this will help